# Swift: What is a better way to implement a game loop for dice roll game (without using wait delay)

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, skaction, game-loop

I am building a simple dice roll game.

The game cycle is like this:

1) Roll dice and move piece

2) Check if there is extra bonus moves, if Yes then move the piece

3) Check if piece has reached its destination, if Yes then Game ends

4) End turn

I built my Game loop using SKAction.run statements and append them into an array and then run them.

The actual code is very long, so I am providing only the basic flow here.

```
func runDiceRoll() {

// some SKActions

}


func checkExtraMoves() {

// run some SKActions depending on runDiceRoll() outcome

}


func checkStatus() {

// code to check if Game ends, depends on checkExtraMoves() outcome

}


func endTurn() {

// code to end the player's turn and give it to the other player

}
```

My game loop looks something like this

```
func runGameCycle() {
var actions = [SKAction]()
let actionRun = SKAction.run {runDiceRoll()}
let actionCheckExtraMoves = SKAction.run {checkExtraMoves()}
let actionCheckStatus = SKAction.run {checkStatus()}
let actionEndTurn = SKAction.run {endTurn()}
let actionWait = SKAction.wait(forDuration:2.0)

actions.append(actionRun)
actions.append(actionWait)
actions.append(actionCheckExtraMoves)
actions.append(actionCheckStatus)
actions.append(actionEndTurn)


piece.run(SKAction.sequence(actions))

}
```

If I remove the Wait action, then the game play is not correct.

I would prefer not to use a Wait duration because it is just an estimate that the preceeding actions will be completed in 2 seconds or less.

I think it would be better if all the actions waits for the preceeding action to complete before firing. I am not sure how to use a completion handler or DispatchQueue for such purposes.

Is there a better way, more foolproof way to write the game loop?

Comment: Can you show the code in `runDiceRoll` and `checkExtraMoves`? I feel like they are important.

Comment: How does `runGameCycle` relate to the overall structure of your game? Can't you just initiate the next iteration of `runGameCycle` (or whatever should happen) in `endTurn`?

Comment: You want a state machine